# Adding an empty value between joined ranges using arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, textjoin

I want to join each value in a range with another selected range (array), but adding an empty value between them for better readability.

```
values to join: {"A","B","C"}
<0>
A   B
CAT <formula goes here>
DOG

<1>
A   B
CAT CAT_A
DOG CAT_B
    CAT_C
    DOG_A
    DOG_B
    DOG_C

<2>
A   B
CAT CAT_A
DOG CAT_B
    CAT_C

    DOG_A
    DOG_B
    DOG_C
```

So I did **`<1>`** with

```
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(split(textjoin("|",1,(concat(filter([range],[range]<>""),"_"&{"A","B","C"}))),"|")))
```

but I don't know how to add an empty value to make **`<2>`**.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kQfOJRo2E51ZrTxN1Vol9oymRmDbvfGLs7YkN1l2ojs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 FILTER("♦"&A4:A, A4:A<>"")&"_"&{"A", "B", "C♦"}), "|")),,999^99), "♦"))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: It worked great except for that non-last cells have a space at the end of strings, but I guess that's how this formula works.